# Por qué no funciona setOnClickListener en Fragment Android SDK

Tags: android

En mi código tengo la necesidad de implementar un `setOnClickListener` pero dentro de un `Fragment` pero cuando trato de hacer tengo error **No puede ser resuelto el simbolo setOnClickListener**, alguien me podria decir como corregir esto?

Aqui esta mi codigo:

```
public class TerminalFragment extends Fragment implements ServiceConnection, SerialListener {
.
.   
mHexBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v) {
    .
    .
    }
});
```

Comment: Eso es porque no estas enlazando bien el botón `mHexBtn`. Muestra el método `onCreateView()` y el layout del fragmento para poder identificar el error.

Comment: debes mostrar mas codigo, lo mas probable es que no estes creando bien una referencia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La forma correcta de asignar el listener de acuerdo a tu código es, dentro del método `onCreateView()` debes inflar la vista que contiene el boton, asignar el listener y posterioremente muy importante retornar la vista que inicialmente inflaste.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{ 
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.myfragment, container, false);


    mHexBtn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.mybutton);


    mHexBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            ...
            ...

        }
    });

    return view;
}
```

El problema principal que muestra el error :

> Cannot Resolve Symbol 'setOnClickListener'

Se debe a que no se esta inicializando el listener dentro de `onCreate()` o en este caso `onCreateView()` puesto que estas utilizando un `Fragment`